# How To Hit Controller Action Using Ajax In Asp.net MVC?

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc

Here i am trying to delete data on button click on AJAX call. But the problem is that on clicking the button there is not hit on controller action even though the parameter to the action i.e id from ajax has a value.
Below is my AJAX

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $("button#btnDeleteContestant").click(function () {
        debugger;
        var contstantId = $("#contestantId").val();
        var parameter = { id: contstantId };

        $.ajax({
            url: "/Contestant/DeleteConfirm",
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "html",
            data: parameter,
            success: function (data) {
                debugger;
                $("div.modal-content").empty();
                $("div.modal-content").html(data);
                $("#myModal").modal();

            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Below is my action in controller

```
  [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult DeleteConfirm(int id)
    {
        try
        {
            _contestantService.Delete(id);
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        catch
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
```

Comment: @VincentJames "dataType" tells the client what to expect back from the server. "contentType" tells the server what is being sent. But jQuery will convert the `parameter` Javascript object (note NOT JSON - JSON is text) into url-formencoded data before sending it (because that's the default contentType if not specified). Your comment is incorrect.

Comment: CarrotCrop  you should be using URL.Action to generate the URL to make sure it gets the right route, and also return a Partial View from your controller - a whole view will include all the HTML body tags and all your layout page.

Comment: As for the reason it's not being hit at all - does your button also post back? Make sure you use `<button type="button"` or use preventDefault() in your JS event handler to stop this. And then check your browser's console / network tools to see what's going on and whether the ajax call is happening or not, and what response you get. If you don't understand what it tells you, post the information here in your question

Comment: P.S. I think you can just do `data: constantId` directly in your ajax, since the controller only accepts a simple integer

Comment: And possibly you need to put `[FromBody]` before the `int id` in the controller action.

Comment: I copied your exact code, everything, and the AJAX triggers and works fine on my part.

Answer (score 1):

The only problem here i see is that it is possible that the url is not correct, so what you can do is utilize `Url.Action` method which would take care of generating the correct urls for a controller action method:

```
url: "@Url.Action("DeleteConfirm","Contestant")"
```

Hope it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few thing that could be the issue with the way you have it now. I suggest you use the $.post because it assumes some things that otherwise you have to specify yourself. So I suggest doing:

```
$("button#btnDeleteContestant").click(function () {
    var contstantId = $("#contestantId").val();
    $.post('@Url.Action("DeleteConfirm","Contestant")', { id: contstantId }, function(data){
        // success handler code here...
    });
});
```

$.post ensures that you are doing a form post which you have to explicitly say when using $.ajax. Make sure that your controller action is decorated with HttpPost attribute. Also make sure that the action's parameter name is "id" to match what you have in your JSON object. If your code is already on the razor view, you should use the @Url.Action helper to construct the url for your button click.

If it still does not work use browser's web tools to verify that the click actually makes the request and then see what request it makes and what kind of response, if any, are you getting.

If you want to stick with $.ajax then I think you also need to specify the the content type as 'application/json; charset=utf-8' and stringify your json:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("DeleteConfirm","Contestant")',
    type: "POST",
        dataType: "html",
        data: JSON.stringify(parameter),
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        success: function (data) {
            debugger;
            $("div.modal-content").empty();
            $("div.modal-content").html(data);
            $("#myModal").modal();
        }
    });
```

Comment: there's no particular reason I can think of why sending as JSON would be required, especially as it's just a simple integer parameter.

Comment: I don't see that written in the question. JSON is not even mentioned